# Returning defeated to something old and familiar

Tags: idioms

What is a good English expression for returning defeated to something old and familiar after trying a new and challenging thing?

For example: *After you spend a year in New York City, you will come back _________ to the good old Midwest.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll **come crawling back**:

> **come/go crawling to**: to go to (someone) for help or approval in a way that shows one is weak or sorry for what one has done
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come/go%20crawling%20to)</sub>

Here's an example that's very close to yours:

> The old men sipping coffee at the local diner like to say, “You’ll come crawling back home soon enough.”
>   <sub>[I Left My Small Town And Never Came Back](https://thoughtcatalog.com/carrie-neer/2017/01/i-left-my-small-town-and-never-came-back/)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

**"with your tail between your legs"**

[Collins Dictionary says](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with-your-tail-between-your-legs):

> If you say that you have your tail between your legs, you are emphasizing that you feel defeated and ashamed.